# Heroku Single User Node App, do I need Redis

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a simple node app for broadcast messaging using socket.io. It will have 3 users at a time

user 1: Moderator (gets a stream of social media comments from various APIs, picks messages to send to user 2 and user 3)

user 2: Graphics (displays messages pushed from user 1 as graphics in OpenBroadcastSoftware)

user 3: Host (displays messages pushed from user one on an iPad (to field viewer questions)

This is all for realtime use, nothing needs to get saved or logged.

I know all the basics of sending and receiving socket.io messages.

My question is, for portability, I want to host this App on Heroku

If this was a single Free/Hobby dyno app, would I need any sort of backend like Redis? Or would it work as if i was hosting the app on a local server since there is only once instance?

This app is never going to have more than the 3 users described above, so I'm not looking to implement any scaling what-so-ever

Thanks!

Comment: Redis isn't a backend it's an in memory data store, you're either using redis or you aren't. If you're using redis to store anything in your code then you'll need redis on your heroku app, otherwise you won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You don't. The websocket can work with just the app, tested it out.